# Python SymPy solve vs. nonlinsolve

Tags: python, sympy

[SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) recommends to use *nonlinsolve* instead of *solve* to solve nonlinear equations.

```
from sympy import * 
x, y = symbols('x, y')
eq1 = Eq(diff(8*x**0.5*y**0.5, x)/10, diff(8*x**0.5*y**0.5, y)/8)
eq2 = Eq(40, 10*x + 8*y)
nonlinsolve([eq1, eq2], [x, y])
```

But this returns: {(-4*y/5 + 4, y)}

If I use *solve*

```
solve([eq1, eq2], [x, y])
```

It gives me the correct solution: {x: 2.00000000000000, y: 2.50000000000000}

Is there any way to obtain the correct solution using *nonlinsolve*? Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Why is nonlinsolve returning the wrong answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469047/in-sympy-why-is-my-solution-nonlinsolve-returning-the-wrong-answer) seems to suggest some problems with `nonlinsolve()`. Also, you could try to avoid floats, and use `x, y = symbols('x, y', positive=True)` and `sqrt(x)` instead of `x**0.5`. Sympy usually isn't very happy with floats.

Comment: I used `sqrt(x)` instead of `x**0.5`, and `nonlinsolve()` worked! Thanks!